# Feature extraction in Keras

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I am using pretrained `resnet50` and `inception v3` networks to extract features from my images, which I then use with my ML algo.

Which layers are recommended for feature extraction?

I am currently using: `"mixed10"` in `Inception v3` and `"avg_pool"` in `resent50`. The features are modelling well in `XGBoost` though.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general rules on how to choose the layer for feature extraction but you might use a easy rule of thumb. The deeper you go to the network - the less `ImageNet` specific semantic features you would have. But in the same time - you are getting less *semantic* features also.

What I would do is to use the `pool` layers in both topologies - and if this didn't work well - then I would go deeper by setting the depth as metaparameter.

Comment: Do you mean "avg_pool" with include_top=True (default) or "global_average_pooling2d_1" with include_top=False?

Comment: In which topology?

Comment: resnet50 has 'avg_pool' for include_top=True and False. inceptionv3 has 'global_average_pooling2d_1' for include_top=False and 'avg_pool' for include_top=True. It seems to me that correct approach to extract features is to start with include_top=True (default) with 'avg_pool' layer for either resnet50 or inceptionv3. Is that correct?

Comment: Seems ok for me also.

Comment: A related point: do you find it necessary to normalize the extracted feature vectors before using in an ML algo or for similarity metrics?